# DB2 on zOS catalog table for schemas?

Tags: database, db2, zos

I did not find any catalog table to get the list of schemas in database.( Like we have syscat.schemata in LUW).

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATOR` in `[SYSIBM.SYSTABLES][1]` is the schema name. You could run

`select distinct creator from sysibm.systables`

to get all schema names.